# Prove that $(A \cap B) \cup A = A$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How can (A∩B)∪A = A can be proved ?

Here  is my proof:

$(A \cap B) \cup A = \{x : x \in A \cap B \text{ or } x\in A\} = \{x : (x\in A \text{ or } x \in A) \text{ and } (x \in B \text{ or } x \in A)\} = \{x : x \in A \text{ and } x \in B \cup A\} = \{x : x \in A\}$

Is the aforementioned proof correct and can it be considered as a formal proof for the problem ?

Comment: Please use Mathjax to format your question.

Comment: An alternative way which I don't see below is to show that $A \cap B \subseteq A$, and from this it follows that $A \cup (A \cap B) = A$.

Comment: Your first equality is wrong; “$\{ x\mid x\in A\cap B\text{ and }x\in A\}$” should be $\{x\mid x\in A\cap B\text{ or } x\in A\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your motivation is correct, some mistakes arose - if you have an intersection, you use "and"; for union, it should be "or." That is to say,

$$x \in A \cap B \implies x \in A \; \text{and} \; x \in B$$

$$x \in A \cup B \implies x \in A \; \text{or} \; x \in B$$

Fix those sort of mistakes and you should be good, though. In terms of formality this is perfectly fine, you just made some minor mix-ups.

Also, a minor thing. If you have two sets of statements separated by "and", you might want to group together which specifically are meant by the "and". For example if we have statements $P,Q,R$, the phrasing "$P$ and $Q$ or $R$" is ambiguous. It could at first glance mean "($P$ and $Q$) or $R$" or "$P$ and ($Q$ or $R$)."

I like to do proofs like this sequentially like below to avoid such problems:

$$\begin{align}
x \in (A \cap B) \cup A &\implies x \in A \cap B \; \text{or} \; x \in A\\
&\implies (x\in A  \; \text{and} \; x\in B) \; \text{or} \; x \in A\\
&\implies \cdots \text{etc.}
\end{align}$$

As a further tip, I would consider two cases at this point, based on the "or" statement. Then for each case I would show  $x\in A$ eventually.

The overarching idea for my approach being that $X \subseteq Y$ and  $Y \subseteq X$ implies $X = Y$, and you can show $X \subseteq Y$ if $x \in X \implies x \in Y$ (and similar for the other case). Granted this is merely because I find it easier to think in terms of this sort of way - if you find your way easier, more power to you.

Comment: Can I please be recommended a book on elementary set theory ?

Comment: @Aditya I highly recommend https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Revised-Expanded-Chapman-Mathematics-ebook/dp/B078JLT9N3/.

Answer (score 2):

To prove $(A \cap B) \cup A = A$, prove both $(A \cap B) \cup A \subseteq A$ and $A \subseteq (A \cap B) \cup A$.

To prove the first inclusion, let $x \in (A \cap B) \cup A$. Then $x \in A \cap B$ or $x \in A$.

- *Case 1:* $x \in A \cap B$. Then $x \in A$ (and $x \in B$).
- *Case 2:* $x \in A$. Done.

In either case, $x \in A$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, $(A \cap B) \cup A \subseteq A$. To prove the second inclusion, let $x \in A$. Then $x \in (A \cap B) \cup A$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, $A \subseteq (A \cap B) \cup A$.

Therefore, $(A \cap B) \cup A = A$.

Answer (score 1):

For me what you've done is almost correct. But I would do it in the following way:

Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $(A\cap B)\cup A$. Therefore $x \in A \cap B$ or $x \in A$, which is the same as $x \in A $ and $x \in B$ or $x \in A$ which implies that $x \in A$.

Now suppose that $x \in A$. Therefore $x \in K \cup A$ where $K$ is any arbitrary set. Let $K = A \cap B$. Therefore $x \in (A\cap B)\cup A$.

That way you've shown that any element in $(A\cap B)\cup A$ is in $A$ and any element of $A$ is in $(A\cap B)\cup A$. With that you can conclude that $(A\cap B)\cup A = A$.

Answer (score 1):

In $(A \cap B) \cup A = A$, $A\cap B$ consists of all elements in where $A$ and $B$ overlap.  Thus, any element, say $x \in A$.  This is unioned with $A$ itself, so we get exclusively members of $A$ unioned with all members of $A$, resulting in the set $A$.  So, $(A \cap B) \cup A = A$.

To make myself clear $B$ is irrelevant as we then combine it, a subset of $A$, with all members of $A$.

As a side note, this is actually [Absorption Rule 2 of Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Monotone_laws).

Answer (score 1):

Option:

Let $A,B \subseteq X$:

1) $A \subseteq A \cup (A\cap B)$;

2) $A = $

$(A \cap B)\cup (A \cap B^c) \subseteq (A \cap B ) \cup A$;

Note : $B^c = X$ \ $B$

Comment: Aditya.Thanks for editing.

Comment: Aditya.A book with lots of worked examples is Shaum's Outline You can download https://www.scribd.com/doc/138378781/Schaum-s-Outline-Set-Theory.

Answer (score 1):

Below an attempt at proving the equality using only the laws of the algebra of sets.

I use the algebra of set definition of inclusion :

Set $S$ is included in set $T$ iff  $S \cap T^c  = ∅$

**First direction** :

$A \cap ( (A \cap B)  \cup A)^c$

$= A \cap ( (A \cap B)^c  \cap A^c)$

$= A \cap (A^c \cap (A \cap B)^c )$

$= (A \cap A^c) \cap (A \cap B)^c$

$= ∅ \cap (A \cap B)^c$

$= ∅$

So $A$ is included in $(A \cap B) \cup A$

**Second direction** :

Suppose that $(A \cap B) \cup A$ is not included in $A$. 
It would mean that :

$( (A \cap B)  \cup A)  \cap A^c \not= ∅$

$( (A \cap B) \cap A^c) \cup  (A \cap A^c) \not= ∅$

$( (A \cap A^c) \cap B)  \cup (A  \cap A^c) \not= ∅$

$(∅ \cap B)  \cup ∅\not= ∅$

$∅ \cup ∅\not= ∅$

$∅ \not= ∅$, a contradition.

So $(A\cap B) \cup A$ is  included in $A$

**Conclusion** : since $(A \cap B) \cup A$   and  $A$ are included in one another, the two sets are equal.